# Current blog is returning ID of 1 instead of users blog ID?

Tags: multisite

I'm trying to update an option for the network blog the user is on but get_current_blog_id() is returning 1 for every blog.

I'm using the JSON-API plugin and I do the following:

1. user logs in at www.example.com/default_site.
2. everything seems to work fine except I get id of 1 for that method

Comment: Might be better aimed at the plugin's developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because WPMU has an admin account that defaults to the same URL as the install.

So my admin user, who is also the default user, let's call him "adminUser", could log in at

```
http://www.example.com/blog/
```

He could update, add new posts, whatever and his posts show up at:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/
```

But when new user, let's call him, "JoeHermermerphermer", comes along, he can register and login at:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/
```

but after login he needs to make calls to his own site URL:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/JoeHermermerphermer
```

The website would probably have redirected him to his site on login, but when using a plugin, I must manually redirect calls to the new URL.

It seems the `get_current_blog()` method looks at the URL you are on.